Contour Integral of tan(t+ai)
I'm working on a complex analysis qualifying exam, and I'm stuck on the following problem:
Evaluate $\int_0^\pi \tan(t+ai)dt$ for $a\neq 0$.
I would like to be able to solve this using a contour integral. Since $\tan(t+ai)=\sin(t+ai)/\cos(t+ai)$, I know the singularities occur when $t+ai=(2k+1)\pi/2$. I think a box contour with vertices $-ai, ai, \pi+ai, \pi-ai$ should work, but I'm having a hard time ironing out the details of actually computing the four corresponding integrals and the residue.

As you suspected, a contour $C$ with vertices $-ai, ai, \pi + ai$ and $\pi - ai$ works. As Gary pointed out, there is a distinction between the cases $a > 0$ and $a < 0$. Let us first consider the case $a > 0$ and consider $C$ with clockwise orientation. Write $I$ for the desired integral. Then
$$\oint_C \tan(z) dz = I + \int_{-ai}^{ai} \tan(z)dz - \int_{\pi-ai}^{\pi+ai} \tan(z)dz - \int_{-ai}^{\pi-ai} \tan(z) dz.$$
Since $\tan(z) = \tan(z + \pi)$, the vertical integrals cancel each other out. I.e., $$\int_{-ai}^{ai} \tan(z)dz = \int_{\pi-ai}^{\pi+ai} \tan(z)dz.$$
Moreover, since $\tan(-z) = -\tan(z)$, it follows that
$$\int_{-ai}^{\pi-ai} \tan(z)dz=-\int_{-\pi+ai}^{ai} \tan(z)dz = -\int_{ai}^{\pi+ai} \tan(z)dz = -I.$$
(For the last step we again use that $\tan(z)=\tan(z+\pi)$.)
By combining the above results and using the Residue Theorem, we obtain
$$2I = \oint_C \tan(z)dz = -2\pi i \cdot \mathrm{Res}_{z=\frac{\pi}{2}} \tan(z)$$
(Note the minus sign, since we are considering a clockwise contour.)
The pole at $z=\pi/2$ is simple, meaning that
$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=\frac{\pi}{2}} \tan(z) = \lim_{z\to\frac\pi2} (z-\pi/2)\tan z.$$
Using l'Hôpitals rule, we can compute the limit:
$$\lim_{z\to\frac\pi2} \frac{(z-\pi/2)\sin(z)}{\cos(z)} = \lim_{z\to\frac\pi2} \frac{(z-\pi/2)\cos(z)+\sin(z)}{-\sin(z)} = -1.$$
We conclude that $I = \pi i$ if $a > 0$.
Now, if $a < 0$ then by considering the contour $C$ in anti-clockwise direction, the argument still works, but we get a change of sign when applying the Residue Theorem. That means that $I = -\pi i$ if $a < 0$.

So of $a$ is real and non-zero, then $$
\pi {\rm i} = \int_0^\pi  {\tan (t + a{\rm i}){\rm d}t}  = \int_0^\pi  {\tan (\overline {t - a{\rm i}} ){\rm d}t}  = \int_0^\pi  {\overline {\tan (t - a{\rm i})} {\rm d}t}  = \overline {\int_0^\pi  {\tan (t - a{\rm i}){\rm d}t} }  = \overline {\pi {\rm i}}  =  - \pi {\rm i}.
$$ Your argument should assume that $a>0$.

@Gary Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I have edited my answer.

this looks great, thank you! Why do we multiply by $-2\pi i$ instead of $2\pi i$ in the Residue Theorem step?

@qualsqualsquals To make the integral over a contour well-defined, the contour should be given an orientation. The orientation matters because if you reverse the way you traverse the contour, you would expect a change of sign. Normally, one assumes the contour to be anti-clockwise, similar to how integrals over real intervals are always taken in positive direction. This explains the minus sign, because we considered the contour to be in clockwise direction.
